# Java MVC confusion over how the controller interacts and passing values

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, controller, listener

I am making a blackjack game for a piece of course work and i understand roughly how the mvc works in the sense that the model holds the data the view is the gui and the controller is your listeners however I get confused when the listener is meant to be separate and then it is put in the same class. I am also having trouble accessing parts from other panels for example i have a card value total list on the side which i want to update when i click the twist/hit button which is in a separate panel however the only way ive been able to access this is by making the list public static which i know is wrong.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could give an *brief* overview of the classes in your MVC and what they do.